# NoSuchElement Exception erron when using "find_element_by_link_text"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium fails to find element by link text:

```
    time.sleep(3);
    driver = self.driver
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    findHeaderLearn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Learn')
    findHeaderLearn.click()
    pageTitle = driver.title
    driver.back()
    return pageTitle
```

I get this error:
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Learn"}' ; Stacktrace:

I read extensively through the web but cant find any hints of why it cant find the element.

Added a "implicitly_wait(10)" to make sure the element is visible but it didnt solve the problem.

Any other ideas?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="l-wrap">
<h1 id="site-logo">
<div id="nav-global">
<h2 class="head">
<ul class="global-nav">
<li class="global-nav-item">
<li class="global-nav-item">
<a class="global-nav-link" href="/learn/">Learn</a>   ======> im trying to find this element
</li>
<li class="global-nav-item">
<li class="global-nav-item">
<li class="global-nav-item global-nav-item-last buy-menu">
<li class="global-nav-item global-nav-addl">
</ul>enter code here
</div>
<a class="to-bottom" href="#l-footer">Jump to Bottom of Page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Best guess is there is a frame or iframe above the link.  If that's the case, you'll have to use `switch_to_frame(frame_reference)`, click the link text, then use `switch_to_default_content()` to reset back to the top of the document if needed.

Comment: Hello Richard, I dont see any frames or iframes

Comment: Have you tried `findHeaderLearn = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Learn')`

Comment: Yup, that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different locator, ideally Css Selector or XPath. Don't use `find_element_by_link_text`.

CSS Selector:

```
findHeaderLearn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#nav-global a[href*='learn']")
```

XPath:

```
findHeaderLearn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='nav-global']//a[contains(@href, 'learn')]")
# findHeaderLearn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='nav-global']//a[text()='Learn']")
```

Comment: Problem solved. find_element_by_css_selector solved the issue. Thank you very much

Comment: I had the same problem - why wouldn't `find_element_by_link_text` work in general?

Comment: @YPCrumble It works, but only when it's an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Find element by linktext might not be as reliable as css selector or xpath. Also verify if the element is stale before performing any actions on it